# How do I print the body of a http request in swift 3 using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I'm trying to make a patch request with Alamofire, in **swift 3**, with a **x-www-form-urlencoded** body but it doesn't work. I want to print the body of the request so I can compare with the result when I make the request by postman.

Here is my code

```
let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = ["conversation[emails_attributes][0][content]":text as AnyObject]

alamofireManager.request(URL, method: .patch, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers)
    .response { httpResponse in
        if let error = httpResponse.error {
            print(error)
            completionHandler(.defaultFailResponse(NSLocalizedString("An errror has occurred",comment:"General Error Title")))
        } else {
            print("HTTP: \(httpResponse.response?.statusCode)")
            if let response = httpResponse.response{
                switch response.statusCode {

                case 200:
                    let jsonData = JSON(data: httpResponse.data!)
                    if (jsonData == nil) {
                        completionHandler(.defaultFailResponse(NSLocalizedString("Error on Data",comment:"Message error when data is null")))
                        return
                    }
                    print("Message Created")
                    completionHandler(.defaultSuccessResponse)
                default:
                    completionHandler(.defaultFailResponse(NSLocalizedString("Connection Error",comment:"Connection failed")))
                }
                print("Failed")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried doing `print("request body: \(request.HTTPBody)")` but it doesn't work, the error message was

> error: ambiguous reference to member 'request(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

Comment: `print("request body: \(httpResponse .request.HTTPBody)")`? Also, it may in a (NS)Data, so you may have to convert it.

Comment: For your issue, I'd say that `let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = ["conversation[emails_attributes][0][content]":text as AnyObject]` seems weird. Did you mean `let parameters = ["conversation":["emails_attributes":[["content":yourText]]]]` or something similar: You can test with `let httpBodyData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customer, options: [])` and `let jsonDataString = String(data: httpBodyData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!`